# Remove element from ArrayList using user input and iterator

Tags: java, arraylist

I need to remove an element from an ArrayList, based on the user input. So what I have is an ArrayList where a user can register dogs. Then if the user wants to remove a dog, he/she should be able to do it by using the command "remove dog" followed by the name of the dog.

I have tried using an iterator, but when using it only the else statement is used and "Nothing has happened" is printed out on the screen.

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class DogRegister {
    ArrayList<Dog> dogs = new ArrayList<>();

    private Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void initialize() {
        System.out.println("Welcome to this dog application");
    }


    private boolean handleCommand(String command) {
        switch (command) {
            case "One":
                return true;
            case "register new dog":
                registerNewDog();
                break;
            case "increase age":
                increaseAge();
                break;
            case "list dogs":
                listDogs();
                break;
            case "remove dog":
                removeDog();
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Error: Unknown command");
        }
        return false;
    }


    private void registerNewDog() {
        System.out.print("What is the dog's name? ");
        String dogNameQuestion = keyboard.nextLine().toLowerCase().trim();


        System.out.print("Which breed does it belong to? ");
        String dogBreedQuestion = keyboard.nextLine().toLowerCase().trim();

        System.out.print("How old is the dog? ");
        int dogAgeQuestion = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.print("What is its weight? ");
        int dogWeightQuestion = keyboard.nextInt();


        keyboard.nextLine();

        Dog d = new Dog(dogNameQuestion, dogBreedQuestion, dogAgeQuestion, 
dogWeightQuestion);
        dogs.add(d);

        System.out.println(dogs.get(0).toString());
    }


private void removeDog() {
        System.out.print("Enter the name of the dog ");
        String removeDogList = keyboard.nextLine();
        for (Iterator<Dog> dogsIterator = dogs.iterator(); 
dogsIterator.hasNext();) {
            if (removeDogList.equals(dogsIterator)) {
                System.out.println("The dog has been removed ");
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Nothing has happened ");
                break;
            }
        }
    }


    public void closeDown() {
        System.out.println("Goodbye!");
    }

    public void run() {
        initialize();
        runCommandLoop();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new DogRegister().run();
    }
}
```

Comment: Change this line: `if (removeDogList.equals(dogsIterator)) {`. And the `break` in the `else` branch is probably wrong too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You compare a `String` will an `Iterator` as said by JB Nizet :

```
if (removeDogList.equals(dogsIterator)) {
```

It will never return `true`.
Besides even invoking `next()` on the iterator will not solve the problem as a `String` cannot be equal to a `Dog` object either. 
Instead of, compare `String` with `String` when you use `equals()` and invoke `Iterator.remove()` to effectively remove the current iterated element.

That should be fine :

```
private void removeDog() {
    System.out.print("Enter the name of the dog ");
    String removeDogList = keyboard.nextLine();

    for (Iterator<Dog> dogsIterator = dogs.iterator();dogsIterator.hasNext();) {   
        Dog dog = dogsIterator.next();
        if (removeDogList.equals(dog.getName())) {
            dogsIterator.remove(); 
            System.out.println("The dog has been removed");
            return;
        } 
     }

     System.out.println("Nothing has been removed");
}
```

Comment: @Dorian Gray. Agreed. Not seen that

Comment: Okay but when I try to change the iterator to Iterator<String>, then I still receive an error. I have looked at the documentation, but I don't really understand how to solve this issue

Comment: @Hiwa_X Thats because you are iterating over an `ArrayList<Dog>`. Did you even **try** the code above?

Comment: @DorianGray Yes I've tried the code, my editor cannot resolve the string getName. I do have a getName method in my Dog Class, that is returning name

Comment: @davidxxx @Hiwa_X Seems it should be `if (removeDogList.equals(dog.getName()))`, exactly calling that method you mentioned. Couldn't you fix it for yourself?

Comment: It is my fault, I didn't use compiler and I forgot the parenthesis. In Scala (I work with at this time) parentheses are optional when no arg is needed. Sorry. @Dorian Gray Thanks for your good eyes :)

Comment: @davidxxx No worries at all. I am having a tough time trying to understand the Java code I'm writing. Have you got any recommendations? I am currently enrolled at university studying my first year of Computer Science, and the Java book I am using isn't the best one

Comment: The book I used to learn/support my first years of Java learning are old (maybe 15 year ago). At the time as starter I read Core Java of Cay S. Horstmann, an excellent author. It seems that it still updated for new Java versions. "Core Java Volume I--Fundamentals (10th Edition) (Core Series)". That is a big book, a general reference that handles many aspects. So you can pick some matters when you needed them.

Comment: @davidxxx So what I've noticed is that the removeDog method only works when you are deleting the dogs (the elements in this case) in the order that they are listed in the ArrayList. Is it possible to edit this method so that you can delete the elements without having to delete them from the way they are ordered in the ArrayList?

Comment: @Hiwa_X Of course. But what do you want to do exactly ? Deleting all dogs matching with the name parameter ?

Comment: @davidxxx I want to be able to choose which element in that ArrayList to delete, this done by writing the name of the element.

Comment: Currently you already delete the dog according to a name matching. If the Dogs have the same name, how do you want to allow clients to specify the one to delete ?

Comment: @davidxxx Actually it isn't deleting according to a name matching, that's the issue. It is doing that only if the element is the first on the list, not if it's the second or third one. So let's say that I've got in my ArrayList the dogs [Buster, Tom, Paul], then with my current method I can only delete Buster, not the others. To be able to delete Paul I have to first delete Buster then Tom. What I want to do is to be able to delete one/many of these dogs, without any specific order

Comment: Oh. So I don't think that you didn't use the last code I posted. In your actual code, you have a `break` statement in the `else`, that is when the element doesn't match. You don't need this `break`. In fact you don't need the `else` at all. I will update

Comment: @davidxxx It worked! Thanks a lot for the help, I truly appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

An `Iterator<Dog>` can't possibly be equal to a `String`: they don't even have the same type.

Only a String can be equal to a String.

You want to get the `next` value of the iterator, which is a Dog. Then you want to compare the name of the dog with the String input.

And then you want to remove the dog, using the iterator's `remove()` method. Read the [javadoc of Iterator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html).